# Manual Order - Update each Order Item Meta Label with a Prefix

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

**Information**

WooCommerce version: 3.6.2

WordPress version: 5.1.1

---

When creating and saving a manual order via Admin, I am trying to replace the wc-item-meta-label with a prefix *(meta key label Prefix is **`RAQ_`** )*

---

Screenshots:
During order creation I would enter
[image: Manual entry]

I am trying to get it updated with a prefix for `each Order Item Meta label` **on save**
[image: On order creation / save]

---

Code tried so far:

```
add_action( 'save_post_shop_order', 'add_prefix_order_item_meta_data', 1000);
function add_prefix_order_item_meta_data( $order_id ){
    // Ensure that this is a manual new order 
    if( $created = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_created_via', true ) ) {
        return $order_id;
    }

    // Check the user’s permissions (for 'shop_manager' and 'administrator' user roles)
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_shop_order', $order_id ) ) {
        return $order_id;
    }

   if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return $order_id; // Exit if it's an autosave   

 // Get the WC_Order object
    $order    = wc_get_order($order_id); 

foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ){
     $item->update_meta_data( 'RAQ_'. $item_id);
      $order->save(); // Save order data
}
}
```

But I am unable to make it work and update the prefix `RAQ_`.

Any help on this is welcome.